# Bash Script: How to enable for the wildcard in variable to expand in for flow control?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have practiced `for` flow control, referencing a sample script like;

```
if [ $(id -u) = "0" ]; then
        dir_list="/home/*"
    else
        dir_list=$HOME
    fi
    for home_dir in $dir_list; do
```

The above is partly quoted lines from "Flow Control - Part 3" http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0130.php

Then,to check how the wildcard in a variable behaves in `for` flow control, I tried the lines below;

```
#!/bin/bash

binlist="~/bin/*"
   
for i in $binlist; do
echo $i
done
```

I wanted the wildcard to expand and all files in `~/bin/` to be displayed as outputs, but it did not happen. The output is just `~/bin/*`.

If I do not use the variable, and directly assign `~/bin/*` into the list of `for`, what I expect happens, all files in `~/bin/` are displayed.

QUESTION=====

How can I enable for a wildcard in variable to expand?

Or am I misunderstanding what the sample code of the reference site intends?

=============

Thank you for your reading my question!

Comment: binlist=$(ls ~/bin/*)

Comment: I would use an array instead `binlist=(~/bin/*)`, easier to handle filenames with for example spaces and such.

Comment: @StephenBoston Hello! I have tried your advice. If -x option is set, like ` #!/bin/bash -x`, that works. But if it is not set, does not. Now I am confusing why no -x set script does not work.

Comment: @bac0n Thank you for your commenting. As you are recommending to use the array, is it pointing to `binlist=(~/bin/*)`?  Is what you mean that I  could use parentheses instead of quotations?

Comment: Yes that's a puzzle! Interesting.  Does the -x option also produce a trace of the script process? What does `ls -l /bin/bash` look like?

Comment: @StephenBoston I am sorry that I added one letter which is not needed to the variable name! But additional question comes to mind. Why did shell work, though declared variable name is different a bit from the one assigned to for structure list?

Comment: That looks like it should be another question. Happy to see that you have a working script now.

Comment: @StephenBoston Always community members', like you, advice helps me find the solutions. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bash variable for your home directory instead of `~`.

The bash variable for your home directory is `$HOME` so your script should look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

binlist="$HOME/bin/*"
   
for i in $binlist; do
echo $i
done
```

Alternatively, you could use `/home/$USER` instead of `$HOME` like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

binlist="/home/$USER/bin/*"
   
for i in $binlist; do
echo $i
done
```

You can view each one of these variables by running the following commands:

```
echo $HOME
echo $USER
```

[These are listed under "Shell Variables" on the bash manpage.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bash.1.html#:%7E:text=HOME)

---

Also, [as mentioned by @John1024](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269374/bash-script-how-to-enable-for-the-wildcard-in-variable-to-expand-in-for-flow-co#comment2149317_1269374), the tilde will not expand to `$HOME` if it is placed within quotes so your third option would be to use the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

binlist=~/"bin/*"
   
for i in $binlist; do
echo $i
done
```

and [as mentioned by @bac0n](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269374/bash-script-how-to-enable-for-the-wildcard-in-variable-to-expand-in-for-flow-co/1269474?noredirect=1#comment2149891_1269474) the quotation marks are not necessary here so you can also use the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

binlist=~/bin/*
   
for i in $binlist; do
echo $i
done
```

Comment: I have gotten what is my mistake thanks to your advice. Especially, the third option is new for me. I have always put characters between double quotations. Thank you!

Comment: Globing will not occur until the variable is used as an unquoted command argument (example: echo *) . `~/bin/*`, `~/bin/\*`, `~/"bin/*"` will all mean the same thing. In general, it is unnecessary to quote a string that does not contain characters that will interfere with the setting of the variable.

Comment: @bac0n Does a string that does not contain characters mean one like any integer? Only if it includes alphabets, does it need to be quoted?

Comment: @CaptainCookie I believe A blank space would be an example of a character that would interfere if not within quotes. For example, you would need to use quotes for the following: `~/"my directory/*"` which would not be the same as: `~/my directory/*` because of the space between `my` and `directory`. However it's not really necessary for `~/"bin/*"`

Comment: @CaptainCookie "does not contain characters that will interfere" :)

Comment: Hello, @mchid ! I had always used quotations,  but now, I've gotten it is no needed in some case. Thank you for your additional support.